# когда нажимаешь на кнопку close в kivy settings, как вызвать метод обновляющий gui самого приложения

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

вот есть кнопка:

```
    btn_settings = Button(text="settings", pos_hint={"center_y": 0.97, "center_x": 0.75},
                          size_hint=(0.5, 0.06), on_release=lambda x: App.open_settings(self))
```

при нажатии на её вызывается метод класса App - open_settings, открываются настройки.
я то сделал отдельно кнопку обновления, но мне кажется что есть способ при нажатии на кнопку close, делать эти обновления.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Благодарю за время уделенное моей проблемме.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решил сам, если кому-то понадобится,в документации описано. Я нашел два решения:
1) `def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
         print("change config", config, "section", section, "key", key, "value", value)`

2) `def close_settings(self, *largs):
        pass`

По скольку класс наследуется от класса App, в нем уже эти методы описаны, просто переопределяем методы и описуем логику под свой код. Мне подошел 1й вариант.